# postgres psql display format

Tags: postgresql, psql

When I put this in my-script.sql :

```
RAISE INFO 'Hello, world!';
```

and run the script with psql, I get :

```
psql:whole path/my-script.sql:282: INFO:  Hello, world!
```

How can I replace `psql:whole path/my-script.sql:282:` with something else (or simply empty) ?

Comment: No, this can't be changed. `raise` was never intended to be used as a "print" alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not appear to be configurable in such a manner.  You would have to make (rather extensive, or very hacky) changes and recompile.

You can get rid of it entirely by doing something like:

```
cat my-script.sql| psql
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, I updated the post. So not even set it to empty, like in interactive session ?